# Error al encontrar la ruta para guardar un archivo txt

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Buenas,
Tengo una web en c# asp.net y en la cual tengo que acceder a una carpeta para guardar unos archivos txt. Lo que pasa es que cuando lo ejecuto desde visual estudio puedo leer y escribir los archivos en la carpeta con normalidad, pero si lo publico en IIS arroja el error:

```
No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'T:\Temp\909720180101.txt'.
```

Es algún tema de usuario?,  o el IIS no puede acceder a la carpeta local por que falta IP?.

gracias.

Comment: Existe la carpeta `T:\Temp` ? Y el archivo `909720180101.txt` dentro de ella? Además sería interesante ver el código que esta provocando ese error

Comment: Quizás es un tema de permisos a la carpeta, podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el nombre del `Grupo de aplicaciones` (application pool) que usas para tu aplicación en el IIS.

Comment: La carpeta T:\Temp si existe pero es algo así como una referencia por ejeplo :  Equipo -> VENTAS(\\xxx.xxx.x.xxx\carpeta)(T:)-->Temp

Comment: El aplication pool, es una como del dafault solo habilite las aplicaciones de 32 bits y version de NET.Framework v2

Comment: Es muy probable que IIS no vea esa carpeta, y por eso no podes guardar ahi.. no importa si se ve desde tu local, una vez que pasaste a IIS maneja el...

Comment: Te refieres a que `T:` es una disco mapeado a una carpeta de red no? Pues por un lado tengo ciertas dudas de que eso funcione,y por otro lado debes asegurarte que el usuario del IIS tenga permisos de acceso a esa ruta

Comment: @JaphSxas al ser una carpeta compartida, por seguridad es mejor que definas un `usuario de aplicación` (si trabajas en un dominio) que pueda tener acceso de escritura. Para luego, en el IIS definas un usuario de paso. En todo caso, me podrías decir si para acceder a la carpeta es necesario tener permisos.

Comment: @Davlio lo que comentas la verdad no lo se hacer, antes no he tenido la necesidad de realizar ese proceso. Podría indicarme como se hace o alguna página o documento de referencia?

Comment: Cuando ejecutas la aplicación desde tu entorno eres cliente y server a la vez. La carpeta T:\Temp debería estar accesible para el servidor donde estas subiendo la aplicación. Esos txt que guardas los crea tu aplicación o son subidos con File.Upload?

Comment: son obtenidos desde otro ubicación como un arreglo de bytes y luego escritos como txt nuevamente en la carpeta que se especifique.

Comment: @JaphSxas ¿Realizaste la prueba con la carpeta compartida libre, sin permisos de acceso?

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Porqué puedes acceder desde tu aplicación ejecutada de tu Visual
>   Studio?

Es porque el proceso relacionado a la ejecución de tu aplicación utiliza tus credenciales para acceder a la unidad `T:`, la cual esta referencia a la carpeta compartida. Se puede dar una excepción de que no use tus credenciales, debido a a que cuando creas una unidad de red tienes la opción de *conectarte con otras credenciales*.

> ¿Porqué el IIS no puede acceder a la carpeta compartida?

Para la ejecución de los procesos de cada aplicación utiliza el grupo de aplicaciones (application pool) que tienen asignados y por ende, como usuarios de tu servidor, no tendrían los permisos necesarios para acceder a la capeta compartida.

---

*Por ello podrías realizar:*

### **Configuración Autenticación de Paso**

A lo comentado, podrías considerar usar una autenticación de paso, para ello es necesario que realices en tu IIS lo siguiente:

1. Seleccionas el sitio o aplicación, y eliges "Configuración básica"
2. Se abrirá la venta "Modificar sitio", en ella presionas en "Conectar como..."
3. Se abrirá la venta "Conectar como", en ella seleccionas "Usuario específico" y presionas en "Establecer..."
4. Se abrirá la venta "Establecer Credenciales", en ella ingresas el usuario y contraseña, y presionas en "Aceptar"
   [image: Pasos del 2 - 4]

Para comprobar que la información ingresada este correcta:

1. En la ventana de "Modificar sitio", presionas en "Probar configuración..."
2. Se abrirá la ventana "Conexión de Prueba", en ella podrías verificar el resultado de Autenticación y Autorización; debería mostrarte los ícones en color verde.

> A modo de prueba podrías considerar tu cuenta de usuario, para mayor seguridad lo que se realiza es definir un usuario de aplicación en el dominio y se le asigna los permisos necesario a la carpeta compartida.

---

### **Suplantación de Usuario**

Debido a que algunas políticas no se considera la creación de un usuario de aplicación, se tendría que acceder a la carpeta compartida a través de una cuenta. Para ello sería necesario agregar el paquete [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) a tu proyecto web.

```
PM> Install-Package SimpleImpersonation
```

En el código incluirías, por ejemplo:

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser("domain", "username", "password", LogonType.NewCredentials))
{
    var fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"\\SharedFile\file.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(fileText);
}
```

Para dicho ejemplo lo que realiza es acceder a la carpeta compartida y lee el archivo de texto.

Comment: Que tal , una consulta es el mismo proceso si la carpeta en la que tengo que crear el archivo es una carpeta compartida de un servidor linux, ya que una BD de oracle es la que tiene que leer el archivo para cargar la data?

Comment: cuando ejecuto me sale el error :
"Error de inicio de sesión: nombre de usuario desconocido o contraseña incorrecta", estoy poniendo mi usuario que tiene permisos para escribir en esa carpeta.

Comment: @JaphSxas En la pregunta indicas que es la aplicación web (publicada en un IIS) quien se encarga de leer el archivo de la carpeta compartida del servidor, en este caso en Linux (para que hayas interactuado anteriormente con la carpeta me imagino que tiene implementado SMB). En el caso que sea un BD en Oracle ya es un tema distinto. El error de autenticación, ¿es en ambos casos? ¿Tu cuenta es de dominio?. En caso hubieras probado en el segundo caso, ¿Has intentado con el IP o Hostname?